# Export to WebGL for React Native

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine, react-native, unity-webgl

I exported my unity scene in webGl format but I do not understand the architecture of the exported folder as well as some type of file ...
'Build' folders containing json files and .unityweb files. ?
'TemplateData' folders containing images and style that I understood.
And an index.html file, ok.

I want to integrate my unity scene in webGl format into a mobile application created in React Native. For that, I want to use the react-native-webgl library that I tested successfully with their examples. However their example is constituted like this ( see the [link](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-webgl/tree/master/example) ). The webGL files are in the src file. There are only Java-script files. What is not the case in the export folder by Unity, there are no JavaScript files ...

How to export my scene in webGl JavaScript for library?

If you have another idea to integrate a 3D planetarium into a mobile application in React-native? I am interested

I think it exports from webGl html and I would like to webGl Javascript .. :/ ??

(My unity project is to make a planetarium in 3D :))

Unity 2017.3 - Android - Application react-native

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to export a Unity scene in React Native without any external plugins, as Unity doesn't support it. However, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unity-view)  plugin will allow for Unity and React to communicate with each other using Web APIs, as Unity doesn't support React by default.

It is important that Unity supports WebGL upon exporting however, otherwise you won't be able to run it on an HTML document.